# How to highlight keywords in a syntax region?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to improve the [cmake-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/pboettch/vim-cmake-syntax) for vim.

I'm unable to have vim highlight a keyword which is inside a text which is already matching a region. I'm talking about variables:

For example `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is a built-in variable which is listed in a `syn keyword cmakeVariable`-list.

When accessing values of a variable in cmake you use `${...}`. Highlighting this is done with a region:

```
syn region cmakeVariableValue start=/\${/ end=/}/
        \ contained oneline contains=CONTAINED,cmakeTodo,cmakeVariable
```

Both highlightings work, except when mixed together. Keywords listed in `cmakeVariable` are not highlighted specially when being in a `${}`-region.

How can I tell vim to apply special highlighting in a region when a keyword is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `contained` argument in your keyword definition. Here's a random snippet that works for me:

```
syntax keyword toBeContained contained foo bar
syntax region fooRegion start="{" end="}" contains=toBeContained

hi toBeContained ctermfg=51 guifg=cyan
hi fooRegion ctermfg=30 guifg=darkcyan
```

Note: This will make keyword `toBeContained` **not** work when it's not in a region that contains it. So you might need to make two definitions, one with `contained` and one without.

I recommend [this great tutorial on creating syntax files](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files), as well as [`:help :syn-keyword`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-keyword) for more information.

Comment: Works as described. Now I just need to find out how to use it for my cmake-syntax-highlighting file ;-)

Comment: It works, it was a question of ordering the regions correctly.